# JMeter Stops sending HTTP requests

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

I am using JMeter for load testing. I have simulate 1500 users with loop count 1. But JMeter stops sending request after 1388 users. I wait for 3 hour but user didn't get increase.
also i am able to access the site under test from another system when JMeter stops sending request, it means server is not under load.

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: I mean JMeter does not increase user after 1388. It shows started: 1500 finished: 1388... and does not go further.

Comment: Please edit ur question with more details and steps. Describe where did u struck. Please provide necessary code if any

Answer (score 1):

**First** of all, run JMeter in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/testresults.jtl
```

**Second**: disable all the listeners during test run. After test execution completion you will be able to open `testresults.jtl` file with the listener of your choice and perform analysis

**Third**: follow recommendations from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) fuide

**Finally**: if you will be still experiencing problems it means that you went above your load generator machine hardware limits and need an another machine(s) to [run JMeter in distributed mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).